# Select element in Firefox won't stay open when parent div has a pseudoelement on hover

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-select

I'm using a CSS `::after` pseudoelement to show content on the right side of a div when it is hovered over. Inside this div is a `<select>` element. In Chrome, this works correctly, but in Firefox (macOS, FF 98.0b6), the `<select>` element often closes immediately after being clicked.

Chrome (the select properly stays open when clicked):

[image: chrome]

Firefox (the select instantly closes):

[image: firefox]

The code is below:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

div:hover::after {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  border-right: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Is this just a Firefox bug or is there a deeper reason for this happening? Are there any simple workarounds?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that `pointer-events: none` didn't truly fix the issue :/ perhaps it's worth opening a bug through Mozilla's official page: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?product=Core&component=Layout%3A%20Generated%20Content%2C%20Lists%2C%20and%20Counters&resolution=---

Comment: @Terry Unfortunate, would've been a nice solution! I have found that making the element always present with an `opacity: 0` and then toggling that to `opacity: 1` on hover seems to work. But still doesn't answer the question of what's going wrong in the first place - maybe it's worth a bugzilla ticket? (Edit: saw your updated comment above, agreed!)

Comment: you can either make the box float instead display:inline-X or, make the select itself float in the box and keep display:inline-X for the box. However , it does look like a bug to me ;)

Comment: Opened a bugzilla ticket, hopefully it'll help lead to a fix someday: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1756514

Comment: Closing the loop, looks like a fix actually went in just about a week ago and should be in FF99! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1440506

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox this can be a bug, although that was some 4 years back this happened. So I believe that the bug is fixed. However if you're still having this issue, I suggest you do the following perhaps this can be helpful to you in this case.

Instead of using CSS, you can use JavaScript. Except maybe you're only after a CSS based solution. But if you're using JavaScript, adding `preventDefault()`
to the event will do it.

```
$('.element').on('mousedown',function(event){ event.preventDefault(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior illustrated above is indeed a specific case of [a slightly more general Firefox bug where dropdowns were not preserved on reframe](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1440506). It appears a fix is in though now and will be part of Firefox 99.

In the meantime, instead of creating the pseudoelement on hover, a workaround is to have the pseudoelement always exist but just toggle its `visibility` on hover, as demonstrated below:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  border-right: 3px solid red;

  visibility: hidden;
}

div:hover::after {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```